# Yii scope related models

Tags: php, yii, scope, relational-database, yii-cactiverecord

I have `Page` model which `HAS_MANY` `Attachment`
In Page model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'attachments'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Attachment', 'parent_id'),
    )
}
```

and I am looking for a way to do some scoping on these attachments.

In the `PageController` I have:

```
    $model = Page::model()->with(array('attachments'))->findByAttributes(array('slug' => $slug))
```

For example in the Page view I would like to:

- get all attachments: `$model->attachments` (this works fine), but also I need:
- get all published attachments (all with `status` = 1)
- get first promoted attachment (the first one with `promoted` = 1)
- get only the images (`mime_type` in_array `'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', ...`)
- get all other files (everything that is not an image)

and any combination of them. Ex: the first promoted and published image

I guess that the best option is to do it without any extra queries and just filter the `$model->attachments` , but is it possible?

Edit:

there is one `pages` table and another `attachments` table

in the attachments table I have: `id`, `parent_id`, `file_name`, `mime_type`, `status`, `promoted`

Comment: First you tell me, what is your model class name ?. Second show me your complete relations method, and third, images, files have separate tables or a single table attachments. show me your attachment table just fields, then i can answer your question. thanks.

Comment: Through attachment relation, you may get only those fields which are in attachment table, if you want other fields, then you need to establish some more relations for images and files.

Comment: pages model class is `Page` and attachments - `Attachment`

the only relationship between them is Page HAS_MANY Attachment depending on the attachments `parent_id`

all the attachments are in one table, and each attachment saves it's mime_type so to be able to get for example `only the images`, `only NOT images`, `only archives`, `only rars` for example

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
$posts=Post::model()->with(array(
    'comments'=>array(
        'scopes'=>array('recently','approved')
    ),
))->findAll();
// or since 1.1.7
$posts=Post::model()->findAll(array(
    'with'=>array(
        'comments'=>array(
            'scopes'=>array('recently','approved')
        ),
    ),
));
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-named-scopes

Comment: is it necessary to use additional query, cant I just filter what already is in the `related` of the Page model

Comment: if you follow that url, you will see that you need to define named scopes, the you can do `$posts=Post::model()->attachments->promoted->findAll()`